# index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Tags: python, arrays

```
import numpy as np

survey1 = [[0, 1, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 1]]
survey2 = [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
           [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]


def makeArray(surveyAnswers):
    array = np.array(surveyAnswers)
    return array

def calculatePercentage(surveyAnswers):
    shapeSurvey = np.shape(makeArray(surveyAnswers))
    index_counter = 0
    answerArray = makeArray(surveyAnswers)
    while index_counter <= shapeSurvey[0]:
        currentBrand = answerArray[:,index_counter]
        print(currentBrand)
        index_counter += 1


calculatePercentage(survey1)
```

hi, I have to loop through each column in the array, I use to a counter so I can do each column subsequently. But I am getting an error message that says that index for is out of bounds for axis 1 with size four. I am new to arrays please help. Thank you.

Comment: Replace `while index_counter <= shapeSurvey[0]:` with `while index_counter < shapeSurvey[0]:`. But anyway, it is a bit weird what you do. You seem to transpose the array manually.

Comment: how would you do it? or what would be the better way?

Comment: what about `print(answerArray.T)`?